# Why does MSVC use SSE2 instruction for such trivial thing?

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, x86, sse, fpu

The code:

```
double Ret_Value=0;
```

on default settings VS2012 compiles to:

```
10112128  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
1011212E  movsd       mmword ptr [Ret_Value],xmm0
```

If SSE2 is disabled in project settings this is compiled to:

```
101102AC  fldz  
101102AE  lea         eax,[Ret_Value]  
101102B1  push        eax  
101102B2  fstp        qword ptr [Ret_Value]
```

**Edit:** I am not sure that `push` and `lea` are related to this initialization, maybe it is for stuff done after that, just disassembly shows them for this C++ line of code.

Is SSE2 significantly better? Except that it is 2 instructions shorter? What kind of optimization is done here?

How this was discovered: the app started to fail on an old processor which doesn't support SSE2.

Comment: I think it is a simple code size optimization. Shorter code is more cache friendly, and so faster. Moreover, not using the stack saves a couple of memory accesses.

Comment: Not sure what the middle 2 instructions are supposed to do. Just to zero the `Ret_Value` all you need is `fldz; fstp [Ret_Value]`.

Comment: @Jester: Probably it is a pipeline re-arrangement (intermix floating and non-floating instructions) because the `eax` in the stack will be needed later, I guess that for a function call or something like that.

Comment: @Jester yeah indeed lea and push seem unnecessary, I will look for more code around it.

Comment: @rodrigo pipeline will rearrange what it needs and intermix what is necessary on the go.

Comment: @rodrigo yes but then similar code must exist for the SSE version too, not making it shorter ;)

Comment: @Andrey this is 32-bit or 64-bit code? By the looks of `push eax` it's 32-bits.... Also, SSE code has higher throughput than x87 code.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist it is 32bit.

Comment: @Andrey then this is somewhat easy to explain. A double is 64-bits, and the widest x86-32 scalar register is, well, 32 bits. It is impossible to clear such a scalar register to 0 and write from it twice to a double's memory location in under 3 instructions, and besides this would be a non-atomic access. While the XMM registers are 128-bits, all of which can be cleared in one instruction (`xorps`), and there exists an instruction (`movsd`) which reads the lower 64-bits of the register and stores them simultaneously to the target memory location (2 instructions). And again, SSE has > throughput.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14865279/17034), it explains why the FPU is evil and Intel decided to replace it.  It took a while before compiler writers followed suit, Microsoft was the last mainstream one.

Comment: MSVC with /arch:IA32 will not generate any SSE instructions for 32-bit code. MSVC x64 native codegen uses SSE/SSE2 and no x87 instructions. MSVC 32-bit using /arch:SSE or /arch:SSE2 tries to use SSE instructions and other x64 native codegen machinery. As of VS 2012, the 32-bit compiler defaults to /arch:SSE2--Windows 8.0 explicitly requires SSE/SSE2 support for x86 (32-bit), and it's already required for all Windows x64 processors.

Comment: SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, regardless of Windows, in case anyone was wondering.  (Of course, in 64-bit code, you could also `push qword 0` or `mov qword ptr [rsp+8], 0` to store 8 bytes of zeros in a single instruction.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intel Optimization Reference Manual section 3.8.1 (Guidelines for Optimizing Floating-point Code) says -

> Enable the compiler’s use of SSE, SSE2 and more advanced SIMD instruction sets (e.g. AVX) with appropriate switches.
>   Favor scalar SIMD code generation to replace x87 code generation.

Section 3.8.5 goes on to explain:

> Use Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 or Streaming SIMD Extensions unless you need an x87 feature. Most SSE2 arithmetic operations have shorter latency then their X87 counterpart and they eliminate the overhead associated with the
>   management of the X87 register stack.