# Why is this loop endless only when I am not debugging it?

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

Below program does some computations to compute how many terms of some infinite converging sum are needed to exceed a certain threshold. I understand/suspect that loops like this may not terminate if rate is too large (e.g. 750, see below) because of computation inaccuracies caused by floating point arithmatic.

However, below loop outputs i=514 in debug mode (microsoft visual studio .net 4.6.1), but does not terminate ("hangs") in release mode. Perhaps even more strange: If I out-comment the "if" part inside the loop (meant to figure out what is happening), then the release mode code **suddenly also outputs i=514**.

What are the reasons behind this? How to avoid problems like this from popping up in release mode? (Edit: I would rather not add an if statement or break statement in production code; this code should be as performant as possible.)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {     
   double rate = 750;
        double d = 0.2;
        double rnd = d * Math.Exp(rate);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        double term = 1.0;
        do
        {
            rnd -= term;
            term *= rate;
            term /= ++i;
            //if (j++ > 1000000)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(d + " " + rate + "  " + term);
            //    j = 0;
            //    Console.ReadLine();
            //}
        } while (rnd > 0);             
        Console.WriteLine("i= "+i);//do something with i
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
 }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on .NET 4.6.1, both 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: Open the Project Properties, look at the Debug settings: optimizations are disabled.

Comment: Although, `rnd` starts off as `Infinity` and ends up as `NaN`. I think `e^750` is simply too large for a `double` to contain. `rnd` stays at `Infinity` until `term` also reached `Infinity`, when `Infinity - Infinity = NaN`, and your loop exits.

Comment: Yes, e^750 is slightly too big to be represented by a `double`, even a denormalized one.

Comment: Floating point math is not consistent between Debug and Release builds when you force your program to run in 32-bit mode (the default).   In Release mode values can be stored with extended range and precision.  Backgrounder for this behavior [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865279/17034).

Comment: @PaulFloyd: denormalized doubles are used for extremely *tiny* values, not for extremely huge values. But, indeed, 1e750 is too large: 1.79e308 is about the limit for a double.

Comment: @Rudy indeed, wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Executive Summary** Your code is broken even in Debug - it produces the wrong result even when the loop exits. You need to be aware of the limits of floating-point arithmetic.

If you step through your code with a debugger, you quickly see what's wrong.

`Math.Exp(rate)` is large. Very large. Larger than a double-precision number can hold. Therefore `rnd` starts off with the value `Infinity`.

When you come to `rnd -= term`, that's `Infinity` minus some number, which is still `Infinity`. Therefore `rnd > 0` is always true, as `Infinity` is greater than zero.

This carries on until `term` also reaches `Infinity`. Then `rnd -= term` becomes `Infinity - Infinity`, which is `NaN`. Anything compared to `NaN` is false, so `rnd > 0` is suddenly false, and your loop exits.

I don't know why this changes in release mode (I can't reproduce it), but it's entirely possible that the order of your floating-point operations was changed. This can have drastic affects on the output if you're dealing with both large and small numbers at the same time. For example, `term *= rate; term /= ++i` might be ordered such that `term * rate` always happens first in Debug, and that multiplication reaches `Infinity` before the division happens. In Release, that might be re-ordered such that `rate / ++i` happens first, and that stops you from ever hitting `Infinity`. Because you started off with the error that `rnd` is always `Infinity`, your loop can only break when `term` is also `Infinity`.

I suspect it may depend on factors such as your processor, as well.

**EDIT:** See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864238/coercing-floating-point-to-be-deterministic-in-net/14865279#14865279) by @HansPassant for a much better explanation.

So again, while the difference between hanging and not hanging may depend on Debug vs Release, your code never worked in the first place. Even in Debug, it produces the wrong result!

If you're dealing with large or small numbers, you need to be careful about the limits of double precision. Floating-point numbers are complex beasts, and have lots of subtle behaviour. You need to be aware of that, see for example this famous article: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Be aware of the limits, the issues with combining large and small numbers, etc.

If you're working near the limits of floating-point, you need to test your assumptions: make sure that you're not dealing with numbers which are too large or too small, for example. If you expect an exponentiation to be less than `Infinity`, test that. If you expect a loop to exit, add a guard condition to make sure it exits with an error after a certain number of iterations. **Test your code!** Make sure that it behaves correctly in the edge cases.

Also, use a big number library where appropriate. If possible, rework your algorithm to be more computer-friendly. Many algorithms are written such that they're elegant for mathematicians to write in a textbook, but they're impractical for a processor to execute. There are often versions which do the same things, but are more computer-friendly.

> I would rather not add an if statement or break statement in production code; this code should be as performant as possible.)

Don't be afraid of a single if statement in a loop. If it always produces the same result -- e.g. your break is never hit -- the branch predictor very quickly catches on and the branch has almost no cost. It's a loop with a branch which is unpredictable that you need to be careful of.

Comment: So the fact that this code wasn't doing it's job was obvious to me. As said, I was mostly wondering how the difference between adding and removing the "if" arose. Reading @HansPassants answer (and the entire question) did a lot to clarify, but the "if" kinda remains a mystery.