# Why .NET 5.0 and Framework in C# does not return same value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

I have two values like below,

`V1 = 44194.291666666664` and `v2 = 44193`.

Below operations returns different values in .NETCore and .Framework

| Product results | **Arithmetic operation** : (v1 - v2) | **ToString()** (v1 - v2).ToString() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .NET5.0 result | 1.2916666666642413 | "1.2916666666642413" |
| .NETFramework result | 1.2916666666642414 | "1.29166666666424" |

**Code snippet**

```
        double v1 = 44194.291666666664;
        double v2 = 44193;

        double value = v1 - v2;
        string output = (v1 - v2).ToString();
```

Comment: MSDN doc doesn't seem to have remark to this, still says it will print 15 digits and not all 17. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0 `By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.` - use `.ToString("G15")` if you rely on it to be identically

Comment: Try compiling both in release mode and see if they give the same result

Comment: Looks like it might be the 80-bit to 64-bit rounding issue. Are the both `double`s? What CPU and architecture (x86/x64) do you have?

Comment: @Charlieface The 80 and 64-bit numbers seem consistent https://dotnetfiddle.net/SYMd3L

Comment: Seems like a bug to me this line https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c142f162854185ba45f0fab678f8b28d1add3968/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L532 doesn't return `'\0'` so it doesn't enter this if https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c142f162854185ba45f0fab678f8b28d1add3968/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L535 - IMHO report an issue here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: @Charlieface Yes both are double values.

Comment: Created an issue on github on your behalf: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46670

Comment: Many existing questions about this.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit" in the .NETFramework project to get the same value as the .NET5 project.  32-bit projects use legacy 8087 floating point instructions, they calculate with increased intermediate 80-bit precision.  The 64-bit jitter use the solution that Intel provided for these consistency problems, generating SSE instructions that don't extend precision.  Note how .NET5 project default to x64, thus the difference you observed.  [Backgrounder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865279/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant - the duplicate issue doesn't fit at all

Answer (score 1):

This is (likely) by design as of .NET Core 3.0. See this blog post on the change: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/