# Visual Basic in .NET 6 generates double values with too many floating points

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.8

after upgrading my project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 the code sometimes generates false doubles

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5MLM.png) of the simple multiplication and the resulting value

Expected behaviour is of course tmpBetrag to equal '35,4' precisely.

It happens in multiple places in my code, but now always.

What can be the source of this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/

Comment: Use Decimal instead of Double

Comment: Floating point math is [not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  You now run in 64-bit mode, getting 64-bit intermediate values for doubles instead of the 80-bit values provided by the FPU in 32-bit mode.  Which makes floating point [more consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865279/17034) but less precise.  You could force your app to again run in 32-bit mode to get the happy numbers back with Project > Properties > Compile > Target CPU setting.

Comment: "Expected behaviour is of course tmpBetrag to equal '35,4' precisely." <=== that right there is the bug; that's not how floating point works, and if you previously got that result: *it was entirely by accident/coincidence* - that was never a defined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

[Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/),

You can address this by specifying the format, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G15"));
Console.WriteLine(number1.ToString("F2"))
```